# Calling an entire script from a button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to call an entire script on a single press of a UI button. Is there any methods I could use to do this? I'm under UWP settings and using Mixed Reality ToolKit if that helps add more info.

Comment: What do you mean by 'entire script'? What's the difference with calling one method of a script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just call all the logic you want to execute inside a method, and if you want to separate things out just call other methods from that method.